# AngularJS - Textarea doesn't want clear after ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have problem with my textarea.

When I want clear her with ng-click, nothing happens ...

Can you help me ?

This is my code, you can test with Jsfiddle : [My app](http://jsfiddle.net/ehTy6/504/)

If you prefer see it here :

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <div><textarea id="yourid" ng-model="isWriting" ng-change="writeEvent(isWriting)"></textarea>
        <span ng-if="displaySend == 1">Yann says :</span> {{isWriting}}
      <p ng-click="sendYaah(isWriting); isWriting == ''">YAH!</p>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$scope.writeEvent = function(isWriting) {

  $scope.imWriting = isWriting;
  var empty = "";

  if ($scope.imWriting != empty){
    $scope.displaySend = 1;
    // $scope.waitResponse = true;
  } else {
    $scope.displaySend = 0;
    // $scope.waitResponse = false;
  }

}
```

Thank for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `==`(equality operator) to `=`(assignment operator) in `ng-click`

```
isWriting == ''
```

to

```
isWriting = ''
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vr6n6024/)

Comment: @PositivProd & @lin; Thanks :)